# TypeError: add_info() missing 1 required positional argument: 'writer' in Flask

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I have passed on all the variables that are needed in add_info function. But still it show this error. (TypeError: add_info() missing 1 required positional argument: 'writer'). Can't figure out the problem here. I have included all the three files needed.

This is my Table file

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Type(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "types"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable = False)

    def add_info(self,name,genre,director,lead_actor,lead_actress,writer):
        m = Movie(name = name, director = director, lead_actor = lead_actor, lead_actress= lead_actress, writer = writer, mov_id= self.id)
        db.session.add(m)
        db.session.commit()

        d = Director(name = director, dir_id = self.id)
        db.session.add(d)
        db.session.commit()

        w = Writer(name = writer, wri_id = self.id)
        db.session.add(w)
        db.session.commit()
```

This is my funtion inside flask app:

```
@app.route('/success', methods= ["POST"])
def success():
    name = request.form.get("name")
    genre = int(request.form.get("value"))
    director = request.form.get("director")
    actor = request.form.get("lead_actor")
    actress = request.form.get("lead_actress")
    writer = request.form.get("writer")
    
    type = Type.add_info(name,genre,director,actor,actress,writer)

    return render_template("addedinfo.html", message = "success")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with app.app_context():
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

here in your function gets name as self.
try to write your function call like this

```
type = Type().add_info(name,genre,director,actor,actress,writer)
```

Comment: Brother I have written it the same way..Created the object.

Comment: I edited the answer. Parentheses after Type should fix your problem @Mahbub

Comment: Thank You so much brother. There were some other mistakes too. I've solved those and it's working now.